# Grails plugin embeded in application

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm developing grails application and I also created a plugin and packaged it as zip.

I develop on two computers - one at work, one at home. I'd like to embed this plugin somehow in project (lib folder maybe?), so I could commit it with application to repo and then on another machine during dependecy refresh grails could install this plugin.

Is it possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152183/how-to-run-a-local-plugin-in-grails-2-0

Comment: yup, indeed that works. One has to make sure filename is correct thou ;) Then it works better.