# grails: Failed to resolve dependencies - spring-security-acl

Tags: spring, grails, dependencies, spring-security-acl

I'm trying to run-app and I've got an error:

```
Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:3.2.0.RC1
```

Also, I tried "compile" and "Resolve dependences" and error is same.
My BootConfig.groovy:

```
plugins {
    ...
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
    compile ":spring-security-acl:2.0-RC1"
    ....
}
```

And I have a needed plugins in  `c:\grails\grails-2.2.4\plugins\`

```
spring-security-acl-2.0-RC1.zip
spring-security-acl-2.0-RC1.pom
spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.zip
spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.pom
```

I have no access to Internet from my workstation, so I've installed plugins manually.

Please, provide a solution for resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [custom grails plugin solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152183/how-to-run-a-local-plugin-in-grails-2-0)?

From that solution answer by @Don:

```
grails.plugin.location.pluginname = "/home/username/dev/plugins/mypluginfolder"
```

**EDIT**

also what I see in [spring security acl dependencies](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-acl/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy) is that  it relies on `compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:$springSecurityVersion"`, so it is missing from your zip, and could probably be resolved to your ivy or maven cache and not plugins directory. In case of ivy cache the folder will be probably in `~/.grails/ivy-cache/`

Comment: I tried `grails.plugin.location.'spring-security-acl' = "c:/grails/grails-2.2.4/plugins/spring-security-acl"` and it doesn't help. The same error.

Comment: This solution also doesn't help. I decided not using this plugin.