# Multi-module Grails project in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, grails, intellij-idea

Have a very basic scenario (at least in Maven world):

1. We use latest grails 2.3.6
2. We have *Core* project(plugin)
3. We have multiple other projects(*app1*, *app2*, *app3*) depending on *Core* project

Resolution block inside of BuildConfig has "pom true" and dependencies between modules are set up inside of `pom.xml`

This set up works pretty well outside of intellij - you build and deploy *Core* project to your local maven repo then you build other projects.

But in intelliJ I would expect to be able to modify both project(*app1* and *core*) at the same time without having to rebuild *core* project every time I touch it.
 I imported *app1* to intellij then added *core* as a module. Then everything compiled and built fine BUT whenever I try to click on a reference to a class in *core* from *app1* it opens another dependency from target/work/plugins/app1

I tried disabling that directory but it didn't work... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to explicitly rebuild, app1, app2, app3 each time the core plugin changes, define the core plugin as a [local plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8152881/2648) in these apps.