# How to publish a Grails plugin locally and to a remote repo

Tags: maven, grails, publishing, artifactory

I'm building both a Grails app as well as a plugin that the app will use as a dependency. I need a way to make changes to the plugin, publish it locally, build the app (using the new version of the plugin - SNAPSHOT) and then do a `grails run-app` to pick up all the changes.

I also need a way to publish the plugin to a remote Artifactory repo and have the Grails app pick up the "release" (non-SNAPSHOT) version of the plugin. Any ideas as to how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the plugin is under development, make it a [local plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8152881/2648), so that you don't have to redeploy to a repo after every change. For example, for a plugin named 'shiro' whose source code is at `/dev/plugins/grails-shiro`, add the following to `Config.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.location.shiro = "/dev/plugins/grails-shiro"
```

When a version of the plugin is ready to be released, use the [release plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/release) to deploy it to a remote repo.

Comment: Thanks @Don (+1) but based on that other answer of yours (using Shiro) I'm still not sure exactly how/where to make this configuration. Did you put this `grails.plugin.location.shiro = "/home/dilbert/dev/plugins/grails-shiro"` in application.properties, BuildConfig.groovy, or somewhere else? How does the Groovy build know to use this abspath instead of the local .m2 cache? Thanks again!

Comment: And also, how do you switch back and forth between local/snapshot and release?

Comment: @TotesMcGotes I've updated my question to answer your first question. To switch between using a released version of a plugin and a local version you need to edit `Config.groovy` and `BuildConfig.groovy`