# How to make changes to Tomcat 7 plugin source for Grails 2

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails 2.3.11 with the Tomcat 7.0.54 plugin. My Java version is 1.8.0_181.
When I try to start the grails app with https enabled by running

```
grails run-app --https
```

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.crypto.tools.KeyTool

I found an answer on how to fix the faulty code in the Tomcat plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44673672/1037864
However I don't know how to get my changes to apply. When I edit the code in Tomcatserver.groovy nothing happens. My altered code is never executed.

Then I found that the Tomcat plugin is a jar-file (located at "C:\Dev\myproject\webapp\target\work\plugins\tomcat-7.0.54\grails-plugin-tomcat-7.0.54.jar") and that jar file is not updated when i build my project.
In my BuildConfig.groovy it says:

```
build ":tomcat:7.0.54"
```

... so I tried to change that to:

```
compile ":tomcat:7.0.54"
```

But when I try to run the project I get another error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
>       at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
>       at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
>       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 7 more
>       Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

I guess I'm missing some dependencies.
What is the correct way to make the changes to Tomcatserver.groovy and then get it to compile (and replace the jar-file)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151989/grails-2-4-java-8-and-tomcat-7-0-55-2 This is a related question which I can see you went to - have left a comment in response to yours on the posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is another way, but I got it working by:

- Downloading the Tomcat-plugin source code from [Github](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-tomcat-plugin/releases).
- Made [the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44673672/1037864) to the source code.
- Ran `grails upgrade`.
- Ran `grails package-plugin --binary`.
- Copied the new jar-file (`target\grails-plugin-tomcat-7.0.54.jar`) to my main project's tomcat-directory (`C:\Dev\myproject\webapp\target\work\plugins\tomcat-7.0.54\)`.
- Started my main project with `grails run-app --https`

I was now able to browse to my site using https on port 8443.